# Reverse a string as per length of first word

Tags: java, string

I am new to Java Strings.
Actually I have the code to reverse words:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Test2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        System.out.println("enter a sentence");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        String rev =br.readLine();

        String [] bread = rev.split(" ");
        for(int z =bread.length-1;z>=0;z--)
        {
            System.out.println(bread[z]);
        }

    }
}
```

For the above code I get:

> Input :Bangalore is a city
>   Output: City is a Bangalore

But I want the output to be like below:

> Input: Bangalore is a city
>   Output:cityaisba ng a lore

Another Example:

> Input:  Hello Iam New To Java.Java is object Oriented language.
>   Output: langu age Ori en tedo bjec ti sjava. javaToNe wIamolleH

Please help me out

Comment: so: what is your actual question?

Comment: But I want output like this

eg: input: Bangalore is a city
    Output:cityaisba ng a lore

Comment: We won't do your homework.

Comment: please watch index of sentences

Comment: i want  output as per index and length of input @Rugal

Comment: @KhajaFiroz Did you try my solution?

Comment: yup ..but  i am getting errors because of rev[z] and  it is not String array..@MarkoPopovic

Comment: @KhajaFiroz Sorry about that, I've written the answer in haste an made an error. I've edited the solution to use `charAt` instead. It should be OK now. Please mark the answer as accepted if it was helpful.

Comment: sorry @MarkoPopovic.i need output like above..it just making reverse of characters,but i need as per to indices.

Comment: @Firoz Ugh, I finally understand how you want to print the words. This is what happens when a man is doing three things at the same time. I've edited the question again. Hopefully, this will finally be what you want.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way you could do it:

```
    String rev = br.readLine();

    String [] bread = rev.split(" ");
    int revCounter = 0;
    for(int z = bread.length - 1; z >= 0; z--)
    {
        String word = bread[z];
        for(int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++)
        {
            // If char at current position in 'rev' was a space then
            // just print space. Otherwise, print char from current word.
            if(rev.charAt(revCounter) == ' ')
            {
                System.out.print(' ');
                i--;
            }
            else
                System.out.print(word.charAt(i));

            revCounter++;
        }
    }
```

Comment: This looks like what the OP is after. `word.length` won't compile, though.

Comment: @Neftas You are right. I've edited the answer to correct this.

Comment: you got it...@Marko Popovic

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code I get following result:

```
city
a
is
Bangalore
```

So to have it in a single line, why don't you add a space and print a single line?

```
System.out.println("enter a sentence");
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
String rev = br.readLine();

String[] bread = rev.split(" ");
for (int z = bread.length - 1; z >= 0; z--) {
    System.out.print(bread[z] + " ");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I didn't check the validity of your code like GHajba did. But if you want spaces to remain on specific places it might be an option to remove all spaces and put them back according to their index in the original String.

**Remove all**

```
newBread = newBread.replace(" ", "");
```

**Put them back**

```
StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder(newBread);

for (int index = oldBread.indexOf(" ") ;
     index >= 0 ;
     index = oldBread.indexOf(" ", index + 1)) 
{
    str.insert(index, ' ');
}
```

newBread = str.toString();

I came up with this quick and there might be better ways to do this, maybe without StringBuilder, but this might help you until you find a better way.

Comment: The original string you entered. It's just a generic name based on 'bread' you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this (i've used a string as input):

```
    String original = "Bangalore is a city";
    System.out.println("Original : "+original);

    StringBuilder inverted = new StringBuilder();
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    String temp = "";

    String[] split = original.split("\\s+");

    for (int i = split.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        inverted.append(split[i]);
    }

    temp = inverted.toString();

    for (String string : split) {
        int currLenght = string.length();
        String substring = temp.substring(0,currLenght);
        temp = temp.replaceAll(substring, "");
        output.append(substring).append(" ");
    }

    System.out.println("Converted : "+output.toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

Append the reversed words without the spaces into a `StringBuffer`.

```
    StringBuffer b = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = bread.length-1; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        b.append(bread[i]);
    }
```

Then insert the spaces of the original `String` into the `StringBuffer`.

```
    int spaceIndex, prevIndex = 0;        
    while ((spaceIndex = rev.indexOf(" ", prevIndex + 1)) != -1) {
        b.insert(spaceIndex, ' ');
        prevIndex = spaceIndex;
    }
```